# Spring Rest, JsonManagedReferences and cyclic references

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I'm facing an issue where using `@JsonManagedReferences` and `@JsonBackReference` won't break the infinite recursion loop when marshaling the Objects to Json.

I know that I could try to avoid bidirectional relationships but this would not serve very well. Another not desirable solution would be to drop the `@RestResource(exported=false)` annotation and follow the link provided just once.

One example would be:

```
@JsonManagedReference   
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@RestResource(exported=false)
@JoinColumn(name="organisation_id")
private Organisation organisation;
```

with it's counterpart in another class:

```
@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name ="organisation_id")
@RestResource(exported=false)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private Set<OrganisationUnit> organisationUnits;
```

Bot classes have a `@RepositoryRestResource` with nothing special in it.

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface OrganisationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organisation, Long> {

    public final static String ID_QUERY = "SELECT u FROM Organisation u where u.id=:objectId";

    @Query(ID_QUERY)
    public Organisation findObjectById(@Param("objectId") Long objectId);}
```

I know that Jackson 2 should be able to handle to kinds of situations but in this case it does not resolve the issue. Is this known behavior that I'm not aware of?
Please let me know of any obvious flaws as I'm not very experienced using JPA, Hibernate or Spring.

The error message which is provided is:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources[&quot;_embedded&quot;]);
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion
```

I'd be happy about any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Which Jackson version are you using? Jackson 2.2.3 does not have this issue. Its taken care automatically

Comment: Hi, thanks for still looking at this ;) It has been quite a while and I'm not working on this project anymore and I can't remember. Thank you for your interest though!